# Removing elements from html-table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, iteration, removechild

I'm trying to remove certain elements from a html-table using javascript. More specifically I need to remove all the nodes that do not contain two substrings.

I've tried to save the positions of the nodes that do not contain these two substrings and then remove them.

```js
var posToRemove = [];
var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var trTags = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var substring0 = "Foo";
var substring1 = "Bar";

for (i = 0; i < trTags.length; i++) {
  var trTextContent = trTags[i].textContent;
  if (trTextContent.indexOf(substring0) !== -1 || trTextContent.indexOf(substring1) !== -1) {
    //do something
  } else {
    posToRemove.push(i);
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < posToRemove.length; i++) {
  trTags[posToRemove[i]].remove();
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://example.org">Foo</a></td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://example.org">Test</a></td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://example.org">Foo</a></td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://example.org">Test</a></td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://example.org">Foo</a></td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://example.org">Foo</a></td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://example.org">Test</a></td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>2018</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Sadly doesn't work like expected. It doesn't leave in the table only the elements that contains one of those two strings. I've checked the positions saved in the array and is all correct.

Comment: Can you include HTML at the question?

Comment: Sure, one moment.

Comment: Is this what you are attempting? Pseudo: if STRING does contain X AND STRING does contain Y - delete. It's that simple right?

Comment: @RandyCasburn If String does NOT contain X or Y - delete.

Comment: You want to remove the strings not the elements, correct?

Comment: Have you already considered `tbody.removeChild(trTags[i]);`?

Comment: @zer00ne I want to remove the elements, the complete nodes.

Comment: @Cat I tried before but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.push()` the element to `posToRemove` instead of `i` and substitute `posToRemove[i].remove()` for `trTags[i].remove()`. Also the first character of each string should be uppercase instead of lowercase to match `"Foo"` and `"Bar"`.

```js
var posToRemove = [];
var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var trTags = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var substring0 = "Foo";
var substring1 = "Bar";

for (let i = 0; i < trTags.length; i++) {
  var trTextContent = trTags[i].textContent;
  if (trTextContent.indexOf(substring0) !== -1 || trTextContent.indexOf(substring1) !== -1) {
    //do something
  } else {
    posToRemove.push(trTags[i]);
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < posToRemove.length; i++) {
  posToRemove[i].remove();
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><a href="https://example.org">Foo</a></td>
  <td>Description</td>
  <td>2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="https://example.org">Test</a></td>
  <td>Description</td>
  <td>2018</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Bar</td>
  <td>Description</td>
  <td>2017</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask you why your solution works while mine didn't?

Comment: @JessicaJ 1) The case of the first letter of the strings to match is not the same. 2) To reference the `tr` element in last `for` loop `trTags[posToRemove[i]].remove()` is necessary (see bracket notaation), as only an index is pushed to `posToRemove` at `posToRemove.push(i)` at first `for` loop, not the element.

Comment: I tried with trTags[posToRemove[i]].remove() but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @JessicaJ Not sure what you mean by _"doesn't work either"_. If you use `posToRemove.push(i)` then use `trTags[posToRemove[i]].remove()` else use the code at the answer. Are you trying to match `"foo"` and `"bar"` or `"Foo"` and `"Bar"`? The code at the answer achieves the expected output, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct, because you pushed the element instead of i. So at the end you iterate on the elements and remove them directly. But If I save i instead of the element and then use trTags[posToRemove[i]].remove() it doesn't give me the expected output.

Comment: Yes, the initial upper case bug has been fixed.

Comment: @JessicaJ _"But If I save i instead of the element and then use trTags[posToRemove[i]].remove() it doesn't give me the expected output."_ That patterns achieves the same output as the code at the answer. Can you demonstrate that the two patterns do not achieve the same result?

Comment: _"Can you demonstrate that the two patterns do not achieve the same result?"_ In order to do that I should include the real table, I'm not sure I am authorized to do so.

Comment: @JessicaJ You can use the same HTML at the question at a plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate that the two patterns described (the code at the answer and the use of `trTags[posToRemove[i]].remove()`) do not achieve the same output.

Comment: I've updated my question. Your solution still gives the expected output, instead my solution achieve a different (wrong) output.

Answer (score 1):

## `row.textContent.search(RegEx`)

1. Collect all of table with `.rows` HTMLCollection and convert it into an array.

   > ```
   > const T = document.querySelector('table');
   > const R = Array.from(T.rows);
   > ```
2. Run `.forEach()` on the array and at the beginning of each iteration of a row, get the `.textContent`.

   > ```
   > R.forEach((row, idx) => {
   >   const str = row.textContent;
   >   ...
   > ```
3. Next make a regex to use with `.search()` method. search the string from the previous step. The regex is a simple literal search for `Foo` alternation: `|` to `Bar`. The result of the search will be the index of the found substring or -1 if there was nothing found.

   > ```
   > const rgx = /Foo|Bar/;
   > const i = str.search(rgx); 
   > ...
   > ```
4. If the result is -1 we know that this row should be removed and we do so using a `.parentElement` property and `.removeChild()` method.

   > ```
   > if (i === -1) {
   >  row.parentElement.removeChild(row);
   > }...
   > ```

---

### Demo

```js
const T = document.querySelector('table');
const R = Array.from(T.rows);

R.forEach((row, idx) => {
  const str = row.textContent;
  const rgx = /Foo|Bar/;
  const i = str.search(rgx);
  if (i === -1) {
    row.parentElement.removeChild(row);
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://example.org">Foo</a></td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://example.org">Test</a></td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>2018</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://example.org">Foo</a></td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://example.org">Test</a></td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>2018</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://example.org">Foo</a></td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://example.org">Foo</a></td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://example.org">Test</a></td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>2018</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you be able to tell me why my solution doesn't give me the expected output? I've updated my question.

Comment: @JessicaJ `.getElementsByTagName();`  returns a Live Collection. A live collection is updated immediately so when used in a loop it's overall length is affected on immediately. When you remove a tr from the Live Collection, the overall count diminishes on each iteration. To avoid the side effects of a Live Collection, use `querySelectorAll()` -- it returns a NodeList that's static so when you loop through it the overall length will persist. Did my solution help? If so upvote if not at all and a waste of time, downvote.

Comment: @JessicaJ Also I'm doubtful about `.remove()` method since its interface is `Node` not `Element` the difference between them is that `Element` interface deals with tags (ex. `<div>`, `<a>`, `<table>`, etc.) while the `Node` interface picks up on tags, text, and `Document`.  Document object doesn't apply to your situation, but I'm assuming text might. Note in my demo I use a method from the `Elements` interface `.removeChild()`

Comment: @JessicaJ if you are wondering why the accepted answer is successful whilst yours is not is this: `posToRemove.push(trTags[i]);` vs. this: `posToRemove.push(i);`. The former abandons the last loop and presents the remaining elements matching `Foo` and `Bar` criteria. Yours continues to the last loop to reference and remove non-matching `tr`. Although it's an extra step in the process which would achieve your objective, *but* the last loop will shrink progressively and not only finish earlier than expected -- it should look almost random since the index changes on each iteration as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I have upvoted your answer. By the way If I was going to use a counter to remember how many elements I have removed so far from the live collection would this help me to keep track of the overall lenght and therefore know how the indexes have changed after each removal?

Comment: @JessicaJ Yes, but declare the counter outside the loop. In fact you can use the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop and a counter (outside the loop as well.)

Comment: Just tried using a counter outside the loop but the output is still wrong. I am using this `tbody.removeChild(trTags[posToRemove[i-counter]];`

Comment: When doing the loop you divorce yourself from that side-effect of diminishing `.length` so try only: `tbody.removeChild(trTags[posToRemove[counter]]);` <= Don't forget to close parens (missing right paren: `)`).